# Laravel Eloquent: Retrieving record via unique (non-id) values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What is the best way to retrieve a record based on a unique value?

I know I can, for example, use:
`$person = Person::where('fullname', "John Johnson")->first()`

Since the `fullname` only contains unique values, is there a more efficient way similar to when you are using `Person::find($id)`?

Comment: Why is the fullname unique? There might be persons with the same fullname..

Comment: Yeah, not the greatest example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any efficiency difference in terms of the query that is being generated - both queries will generate a very similar SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = 5;
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE fullname = 'John Johnson' LIMIT 1;
```

There can be difference in efficiency that depends on your schema configuration, as **primary keys** usually have **index created automatically** and for other columns you need to **create the index yourself**.